# Sample data for Magento 2 - PHP memory problem while installing from Composer

Tags: magento2, composer, sample-data, memory

Recently I tried to install Magento 2 with sample data and failed. I added the proper package to the `composer.json` file and when I run `composer update` it always fails just before finishing downloading:

```
  - Installing magento/sample-data-media (0.42.0-beta1)
    Downloading: 90%
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 652738560) (tried to allocate 556269568 by
tes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/
RemoteFilesystem.php on line 175
```

I set `memory_limit` in my `php.ini` file to `2048MB` but it didn't help. I checked in command line that it is set correctly:

```
c:\WT-NMP\WWW\magento_2>php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit');"
2048M
c:\WT-NMP\WWW\magento_2>php -r "$a = []; while(true) { $a[] = 'a'; }"

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2019033088) (tried to allocate 24 bytes) i
n Command line code on line 1
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Or maybe you know some hacky way to install sample data without Composer?

Comment: This is not exactly linked to Magento but to PHP. I advise you to use a VM for the installation process since it will make things easier. Later today I will publish an article with a step by step on how to achieve this based on https://github.com/rgranadino/mage2_vagrant.

Answer (score 5):

We apologize for the issues. There have been recent problems with sample data that are now resolved.

We just published updates to the procedure. There are two ways to do it:

Install sample data before installing Magento: http://bit.ly/1FIHnVO

Install sample data after installing Magento: http://bit.ly/1HSALaY

Please let us know if you have questions or issues.

Comment: I am trying to follow those instructions but there is no sampledata:install task for bin/magento script

Comment: The procedure has recently changed. If you *clone* the Magento 2 CE GitHub repo and the Magento 2 sample data repo, you can install sample data using the Magento develop branch.

Try this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web-sample-data.html

Answer (score 4):

I get the same issue. Plus, the download via composer of the sample data takes 2 eternities until it crashes.
Here is what I did.
Download the sample data [from here](http://packages.magento.com/_packages/magento_sample-data-0.42.0-beta1.zip) and unzip what you donwload in `dev/tools/Magento/Tools/SampleData/`.
Then download the media images for the sample data [from here](http://packages.magento.com/_packages/magento_sample-data-media-0.42.0-beta1.zip) and unzip what you download to `pub/media`.
Then, when installing Magento 2, the "Install sample data" checkbox will be enabled.
But be patient. Installing the sample data will take a while.

Comment: Both links are broken. Any replacements? I ran into the same problem..

Comment: links broken still?

Comment: yeah. apparently the links changed. I have no idea to which ones.

Answer (score 2):

Update your memory_limit! If this setting is too low then you’ll get some unusual problems with your install like freezing at 2% or 96% with no error messages. You can change this globally in WHM or just add the following line to the very top of

public_html or htdocs/index.php:

```
ini_set(“memory_limit”,”2048M”);
```

Also set this same line at the top of `dev/tools/Magento/Tools/SampleData/install.php`

```
ini_set(“memory_limit”,”2048M”);
```

I actually set mine to 4096M to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set inline memory limit in the command:

**Infinite Memory Limit**

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

**Setting memory limit 4GB**

```
php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento sampledata:deploy
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer to this question created 6 and a half years ago ;-).