# Installation hangs while installing data

Tags: magento2

I tried to install magento 2 and it hangs while loading module `Module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData':`

Here is my Environment:

Ubuntu 14.04
Ngix
MySQL
I have attached a screen for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try to increase value of `max_execution_time` in PHP to 1800 (30 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Installing sample data takes time.

If installing sample data blocks your installation process, you can install Magento without sample data and then install sample data separately using this manual http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-magento.html

Also try to increase value of max_execution_time.

This link can be also helpful:
[Sample data for Magento 2 - PHP memory problem while installing from Composer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49235/sample-data-for-magento-2-problem-while-installing-from-composer?rq=1)

UPD. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_70pct.html

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Apache+PHP-FPM like myself this might work for you:

```
<Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/m2">
    ProxySet min=0
    ProxySet timeout=1800
</Proxy>

<LocationMatch "^(.*\.php).*$">
    ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/m2
</LocationMatch>
```

The reason it stopped for me was that apache stopped talking to php-fpm proxy.

here is the error I got in my apache log:

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 7698] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 178.79.164.65:36691] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :, referer: http://54.153.44.88/setup/
```

I fixed the problem my setting proxy timeout as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to resume your sample data entry again by using teminal -

be in your root folder of installation

`root@sys:/var/www/html/magento2#`

use below command -

`php -f bin/magento sampledata:deploy`

Comment: No Luck with command `php -f bin/magento sampledata:deploy`. Throws an error `  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.
  You must be using the interactive console to authenticate`

Answer (score 0):

This may also be caused by a missing .htaccess file. (In my case, the . Systemfiles were missed when copying the data)

After adding the .htaccess the installation worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Are you in developer mode?

1 first get the M2 without sample data and unzip it hosting.

2 get in developer mode

3 create the database

4 change folders and files permissions.

5  create a folder and copy all the files right now in the public
    folder in there (is like a emergency folder)

6 unzip the designs and components you plan to use.

7 install.

it should work