# Magento2 sample data install stuck at 90%

Tags: magento2, install, sample-data

I installed Magento2 on a Nexcess server without Sample data without any issues. I then cleared the install (removed the folder completely) I dropped and recreated the database and restarted the install.

The install stalls at 90% and doesn't give me any additional feedback.

Here is the last bit of the log

```
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Installing data.. 

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data..
```

[image]

Comment: It insert 2000 product(install sampledata) to your database so it slowly

Comment: @Bill is correct; beyond that, any webserver or magento error log output?

Comment: I've seen this happening with xdebug.max_nesting_level or max_excecution_time values being to low. You might want to try changing those or shoot us an email to see if we can help.

Comment: @benmarks Nothing in the server error logs

Comment: I know we marked this as a duplicate but doesn't tell us what the problem is does it?

Comment: @brentwpeterson have you tried everything proposed in answers to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92976/installation-hangs-while-installing-data and nothing helped?

Comment: I haven't done the work around where I install after. I have tried the other items. The work around is a "Work around" and not a solution.

Comment: Have you increased `max_execution_time` to 18000 as recommended? https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/.htaccess#L41

Comment: Yes, changing to 18000 didn't help